# fixate background image when fully scrolled down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page:

[image]

It has a background image, which can be scrolled down:

[image]

Unfortunately, as soon as the whole image is scrolled through it either repeats or when `no-repeat` is enabled, is just cut off with no image at all:

[image]

How do I fixate the background image when it is scrolled down fully?

**Edit:**

I wasn't clear enough about what I want. I want this setting to change from `scroll` to `fixed` and back, depending on if the image is fully scrolled through or not:

```
/*as long as image can be scrolled and does not reach its end/repeats*/
body {background-attachment: "scroll";}

<->

/*if end of image reached/repeats*/
body {background-attachment: "fixed";}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] in the question itself. You can likely use a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the CSS for the same

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

OR

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: No need for all of those vendor prefixes; `background-size: cover` has been [available for years in the listed browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_background-size_contain_and_cover).

Comment: This code just fixates the background, I need it to be scrollable until reaching its end and then fixed.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov please submit your code as a snippet.